# Use of unresolved identifier 'PFQuery'

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qcrO8uNzU&feature=youtu.be for Parse and when defining a PFQuery variable I get this error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'PFQuery'".

Code Below:

```
 var getMessages = PFQuery(className:"DevelopmentMessages")
```

How would this be fixed? Thanks in Advance! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the Parse framework in your project correctly. This is done about 7 minutes in during Part 1 of that tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6kTw_cK3zY

It is also covered in Parse's QuickStart instructions:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

All you need to do is the "Install the SDK" portion but you also need to include the Parse framework's header in your Objective-C bridging header:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Comment: unfortunatly I have already installed the framework and set it up. Everything is except the PFQuery is working fine. :(

Comment: Can you access anything from the Parse framework (PFObject, etc.)? If not, the framework is not setup or imported correctly. Make sure you have setup your bridging header correctly.

Comment: yes i am successfully sending data to Parse Data Base

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because you might not have imported the libraries properly. Drag drop the library files into the project properly. Make sure you have added the library inside your project folder and not outside it. Sometimes it may also be the cause of the problem.

Note - Please don't forget to check the option "Copy files if needed" while dragging and dropping the library files.

**Update - If you have named your project as "parse" then it will not work. So rename your project to any other name and try it.**